# checking tic tac toe game python

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

I have to check a finished tic tac toe game and I have to make sure that each row that the user inputs has 3 symbols. I'm having trouble doing this:

```
for i in ttt:
            if i < len(3):
                print("invalid board - too few symbols")
            elif i > len(3):
                print("invalid board - too many symbols")
            else:
                continue
```

ttt is the appended rows.

I get this message when I run it: if i < len(3): TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: len(i) < 3 not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

The function len() doesn't take a value of type int as an argument: the argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).

In this situation, you need to find the length of i using len(), and compare it to the integer 3.

resource: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len